# Wrong value inserted while trying to update the maximum event log file size using EvtSetChannelConfigProperty() function

Tags: c++, windows, event-log

I'm trying to update the maximum log file size of the event log using `EvtSetChannelConfigProperty()` function. I don't get an error during the execution or run time. The maximum log file size is updated. But it isn't the same as I specified in the program.

Program:

```
UINT64 myvalue = 20544;
EVT_VARIANT value;
value.Count = 1;
value.Type = EvtVarTypeUInt64;
value.UInt64Arr = &myvalue;

EVT_HANDLE hlog = EvtOpenChannelConfig(NULL, L"Security", 0);
BOOL check = EvtSetChannelConfigProperty(hlog, EvtChannelLoggingConfigMaxSize, 0, &value);
check = EvtSaveChannelConfig(hlog, 0);

if (hlog)
    EvtClose(hlog);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're setting the property to the *pointer* to your variable, not its *value*.

Instead of

`value.UInt64Arr = &myvalue;`

try

`value.UInt64Val = myvalue;`

Comment: Well, that is correct. 20544000 bytes = 20062.5 KB.

Comment: Oh yeah... Sorry for that. Thanks a lot for the help :)